# Connect in and out pipes to network socket

Tags: c, tcp, pipe

In a C program, suppose I'm running a child process to ssh into an IMAP server:

```
ssh -q -C user@example.com /usr/bin/imapd ./Maildir 2> /dev/null
```

I can then use that process's in and out pipe. Now I'd like curl to connect to that SSH tunnel (in order to use its high-level functions for talking to the IMAP server), but curl will only accept a [network socket](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/externalsocket.html), not a pair of pipes. So how can I relay my pipes to the socket?

I'm ideally looking for a solution that works not only under POSIX but also under Windows.

Comment: How are you starting the child process and capturing its **stdin** and **stdout**?  You mentioned POSIX and Windows, so are you doing it differently for each of those?  Windows has named pipes, for what it's worth.  (See **CreateNamedPipe**.)

Comment: First two `pipe()`s are generated, then the process is `fork()`ed into a child process. In that child process, the in pipe previously generated is first `dup2()`ed to 0, and then closed; same goes for the out pipe (to 1). Then, the combined command and parameters string is parsed into a suitable vector format passed to `execvp()`.

Comment: Bernhard Reiter: Are you using the logic you've described for both POSIX and for Windows?  You'd mentioned wanting a strategy for both.

Comment: Shao: Not exactly, but similarly. Using mingw, in a nutshell, instead of `dup2()`, `dup()` is used, and the handles generated from that are passed to `_get_osfhandle()` to obtain the corresponding OS file handle, which are then used as `hStdInput`/`hStdOutput` members of a `STARTUPINFOW` struct in the creation of the subprocess by invocation of `CreateProcessW()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mkfifo ~/ssh_in
mkfifo ~/ssh_out
ssh -q -C user@example.com /usr/bin/imapd ./Maildir < ~/ssh_in > ~/ssh_out 2> /dev/null
nc -l 143 < ~/ssh_out | tee ~/ssh_in
```

Now your **curl** should be able to talk to **localhost:143**

By the way, you don't have an "SSH tunnel."

Doesn't seem to work with **Cygwin FIFOs**, unfortunately.

Comment: Any way to do this programmatically, i.e. is there a libnetcat or something like that? Also, I was hoping for no additional extra dependencies, so can the same be done (easily?) using e.g. splice() or tee() or something like that?

Comment: Bernhard Reiter: Yes.  Instead of using **netcat**, you can write TCP code.  "libnetcat", in this case, would just be TCP logic.  Then you needn't fiddle with redirection, but could pump the two pipes for SSH's **stdin** and **stdout** directly out of and into the TCP socket, respectively.

Comment: Shao: What about POSIX's `socketpair()`? There's even a ~150 LOC workaround Windows implementation at https://github.com/ncm/selectable-socketpair, which seems more lightweight than using netcat.